# Harmonic series

Tags: ruby

```
1.upto(sums) do |n|

    puts harmonic_sum(n)

end
```

is there a way to label whatever is outputed so if the user enters 6 it counts them as 1 2 3 4 5 6?

Comment: Please give a reference to what harmonic series are and how those are calculated. The dedicated method to calculate them is definitely absent in ruby out of the box.

Comment: `ruby -e'p (1..5).reduce { |r,i| r += 1.0/i }'`

Comment: A harmonic series represents the sum of fractions that follow this pattern:
hn = 1 / 1 + 1 / 2 + 1 / 3 + 1 / 4 ... + 1 / n - 1 + 1 / n

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29 that is a harmonic series and what it is.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, please post that as an answer, though I believe you want `r + 1.0/i`.

Comment: To clarify, your function would take `n` and look like `(1..n).reduce { |r, i| r + 1.0/i }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harmonic series isn't implemented in Ruby standard library, but Rational is :

```
def harmonic_sum(n)
  (1..n).inject(Rational(0,1)) {|r, i| r + Rational(1,i) }
end

puts harmonic_sum(5)
#=> 137/60
puts harmonic_sum(50)
#=> 13943237577224054960759/3099044504245996706400
puts harmonic_sum(10_000).to_f
#=> 9.787606036044382
```

NOTE: Your code is fine BTW. Here are some slight modifications and a few TODOS ;)

```
class Fraction
  attr_reader :numerator, :denominator

  def initialize(n, d)
    @numerator = n
    @denominator = d
  end

  def to_f
    numerator.to_f/denominator
  end

  #TODO: Add *
  #TODO: Define - and / with + and *
  #TODO: Check that rhs is a Fraction, convert self to float otherwise.

  def +(rhs)
    n = @numerator*rhs.denominator + @denominator*rhs.numerator
    d = @denominator*rhs.denominator
    n, d = reduce(n, d)
    return Fraction.new(n, d)
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@numerator} / #{@denominator}"
  end

  private

  def reduce(n, d)
    r = gcd(n, d)
    return n / r, d / r
  end

  def gcd(a, b)
    if a % b == 0
      return b
    else
      return gcd(b, a % b)
    end
  end
end

def harmonic_sum(n)
  (1..n).inject(Fraction.new(0,1)) {|r, i| r + Fraction.new(1,i) }
end

puts harmonic_sum(100)
#=> 14466636279520351160221518043104131447711 / 2788815009188499086581352357412492142272
```

Comment: `(0..n).inject {|s, i| s + 1/i.to_r }` is the same but more concise.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I never came across to_r in my 10+ years of Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for your input it really helped! :)